# Data Generator and WAMP Server

Tags: php, sql, database, wamp

I'm having trouble activating the following script using WAMP:

http://www.generatedata.com/#download

I was trying to move it into the C:\wamp\www directory and ended up doing this:

http://s39.photobucket.com/albums/e191/mistamike888/?action=view&current=Image1.jpg

I understand very little about how WAMP and this whole set up works, if anybody could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Edit: By the way I understand that I need to upload the .sql file in the install folder using PHPMyAdmin, that's about as far as I got though.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm trying to access localhost/ with my browser and getting this error. The Data Generator is suppose to show up on the main page along with other plug ins such as **SQLBuddy** and **PHPMyAdmin**. I can access these directly (** i.e. http://localhost/phpmyadmin/**) but I don't know how I would access the Data Generator.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__));
```

To the top of index.php (under the `<?php` bit).

Comment: It didn't work, I think the issue is that I accidentally overwrote the original index.php file with an index.php file from the Data Generator folder. Does this mean that I should re-install WAMP?

Comment: @Mike No WAMP and PHP are separated beasts, the error is basically saying PHP can not find the file to include. Does the file `C:\wamp\www\library.php` exist?

Comment: Yes, I tried moving it back into the directory but it gave another error: **Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www/code/accounts.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear;C:\wamp\www') in C:\wamp\www\library.php on line 29**